# Java Physics Engine?

Tags: java, physics

I have been playing around with Game development in Java, specifically with the Slick 2d game engine. I have an idea for a simple game, but I need a physics engine.

I have been searching the internet looking for a well-documented, free physics engine. I have never used a physics engine so I am looking for something relatively simple, with a lot of examples and documentation.

Comment: Are you looking for 2d physics, or 3d physics? I'd guess 2d, since you're using Slick...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i only need a 2-d physics engine...

Comment: http://www.jbox2d.org/ might be of interest

Comment: Do you have a problem with Box2D? If so, what? If not, you should really accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

Box2D is pretty much the standard 2d physics library for most games out there. There's a port to Java here which is quite easy to use:

http://www.jbox2d.org/

Answer (score 4):

What about [JBox2d](http://www.jbox2d.org/)? It's a straight port of the more notorious Box2D written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D and 100% java, [dyn4j](https://github.com/dyn4j/dyn4j) can be considerred.